# What causes a Hadoop datanode to die?

Tags: hadoop

I have been running a Hadoop 2.3.0 cluster and I have been noticing on the status page (:50070/dfshealth.html) shows data nodes that have died which happens every couple of days. After noticing a datanode failure, I restart the process with the command:

```
/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh stop datanode && /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh stop nodemanager && /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode && /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh start nodemanager
```

and everything keeps on going.

What can cause a datanode to die? Are there are good tools to diagnose past failures?

Answer (score 1):

The above exception (java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [0.0.0.0:50010]) indicates that there's another instance of our datanode is running, Since you have started datanode using hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode. Data node process is running fine still it is not able to effectively communicate with namenode.

Stop and start namenode and datanode daemons in debug mode, following command can be used.

On Namenode host, Execute the following command

```
/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh stop namenode ; hadoop namenode
```

On datanode host, Execute the following command

```
/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh stop datanode ; hadoop datanode
```

Check the logs messages from both daemons.